# How to run netbeans webapp manually

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Just curious, without using Netbeans for running the web app, how do I run it? I have Apache Tomcat 7. Where do I copy-paste my files? Are there any other configurations?

I tried pasting my netbeans project folder in the webapp folder in apache but it won't build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From netbeans export your project as a WAR file and throw that project_name.WAR file in the Webapps folder and run tomcat.

Also see that you have a web.xml file in your project